# plot Latitude longitude points from dataframe on folium map - iPython

Tags: python, dataframe, ipython, folium

I have a dataframe with lat/lon coordinates

```
latlon
(51.249443914705175, -0.13878830247011467)
(51.249443914705175, -0.13878830247011467)
(51.249768239976866, -2.8610415615063034)
...
```

I would like to plot these on to a Folium map but I'm not sure of how to iterate through each of the rows.

any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Comment: any idea of how I could link such (lat, lon) pairs with a line?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This can solve your issue

```
import folium
mapit = None
latlon = [ (51.249443914705175, -0.13878830247011467), (51.249443914705175, -0.13878830247011467), (51.249768239976866, -2.8610415615063034)]
for coord in latlon:
    mapit = folium.Map( location=[ coord[0], coord[1] ] )

mapit.save( 'map.html')
```

#### Edit (using marker)

```
import folium
latlon = [ (51.249443914705175, -0.13878830247011467), (51.249443914705175, -0.13878830247011467), (51.249768239976866, -2.8610415615063034)]
mapit = folium.Map( location=[52.667989, -1.464582], zoom_start=6 )
for coord in latlon:
    folium.Marker( location=[ coord[0], coord[1] ], fill_color='#43d9de', radius=8 ).add_to( mapit )

mapit.save( 'map.html')
```

It'd be great if you use this reference: https://github.com/python-visualization/folium

Comment: Thanks for that. To add markers I have tried adding 
`mapit = folium.Map(location=[52.667989, -1.464582], zoom_start=6)
for coord in latlon_df:
    mapit.polygon_marker(location=[coord[0], coord[1]], fill_color='#43d9de', radius=8)

mapit.create_map(path='map.html')
`
But it didn't work - Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 22):

Below is how I did it, I'm actually trying to put together a notebook of examples (adding color, popup, etc.). I'm still working out the kinks but you can find it here:

https://github.com/collinreinking/longitude_latitude_dot_plots_in_python_with_folium

```
import folium
import pandas as pd

#create a map
this_map = folium.Map(prefer_canvas=True)

def plotDot(point):
    '''input: series that contains a numeric named latitude and a numeric named longitude
    this function creates a CircleMarker and adds it to your this_map'''
    folium.CircleMarker(location=[point.latitude, point.longitude],
                        radius=2,
                        weight=5).add_to(this_map)

#use df.apply(,axis=1) to "iterate" through every row in your dataframe
data.apply(plotDot, axis = 1)


#Set the zoom to the maximum possible
this_map.fit_bounds(this_map.get_bounds())

#Save the map to an HTML file
this_map.save('html_map_output/simple_dot_plot.html')

this_map
```

Comment: For anyone else that has the same problem as me - I recommend change `weight` to something greater than 0.