# How to create a map in folium using information from two different DataFrames

Tags: python

I would like to create a map using information from two different DataFrames I have already created.

As an example, in the first DataFrame `(df_resultados)`, I have the column `ocorrências_match`, which has a list of Brazilian cities `[tietê, itu, piracicaba etc]`. As you can see here:

```
nome_do_romance autor   cidade_natal    ano_de_publicação   ocorrências ocorrências_match
0   Til José de Alencar Fortaleza - CE  1871    [piracicaba, tietê, atibaia, são paulo, campos...   [tietê, itu, piracicaba, mato grosso, são paul...]
```

In the other DataFrame `(df_new)`, I have the geolocation of those cities in `ocorrências_match`. As an example:

```
    NOME_MUNICIPIO  LONGITUDE   LATITUDE
0   alta floresta d'oeste   -61.999824  -1.193554
1   ariquemes   -63.033269  -9.908463
```

I would like to iterate through these two DataFrames to match the geolocations of `df_new` with the cities contained in the `ocorrências_match` of `df_resultados` and plot them on a map using folium.

I have already tried some codes, but I can't seem to find a solution. The problem seems to be that I hava many cities in the same row (as a list) in `df_resultados`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to explode and merge the dataset, then use it in folium

```py
res = df_resultados.explode("ocorrências_match").merge(df_new, how='left', left_on='ocorrências_match', right_on='NOME_MUNICIPIO')
```

Comment: James Flash, I think you haven't considered or I have not made it clear that in the rows of df_resultados, we have a list of cities. Don't we have to itarate through it?

Comment: I think you haven't considered or I have not made it clear that in the rows of df_resultados, we have a list of cities. Don't we have to itarate through it?

Comment: After building `res` dataframe you don't have the list of cities (due to `explode` method) but you may have some duplicated rows. Then you can plot all cities in the same way like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401729/plot-latitude-longitude-points-from-dataframe-on-folium-map-ipython)